# Cassandra NetworkTopologyStrategy replication

Tags: cassandra

I installed and started Cassandra on two linux machines in Amazon EC2. I also set cassandra.yaml to use a property file snitch and configured the cassandra-topology.properties file as the following:

```
  <external IP 1>=AWS1:R1
  <external IP 2>=AWS2:R1
```

Then created a keyspace as the following:

```
 create keyspace myks with strategy_options = [{AWS1:1,AWS2:1}]  and placement_strategy='NetworkTopologyStrategy';
```

Then I created a column family and tried inserting one row...However, I'm getting a null back from the CLI when I try to insert. Did I miss something in the configuration?

How can I find out what's going on?

Also -- does Cassandra only read the cassandra-topology at startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like keyspace creation is not properly done. Its a simple fact, whenever you are getting UnavailableException() while populating, take it for granted that there is an issue in creating the keyspace. In your case you haven't mention the full class path for the desired placement_strategy

```
CREATE KEYSPACE myks WITH placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy'
AND strategy_options=[{AWS1:1,AWS2:1}];
```

Yes Cassandra only read topology at the time creation of the keyspace(startup)

Comment: You don't need the full classpath, Cassandra will automatically add it. Also, cassandra-topology.properties is reloaded every 60 seconds so you can change this on a live cluster. You need to create the file on each host otherwise you may get UnavailableExceptions too.

Comment: Thank you both -- is there a tool or command in Cassandra that would tell me the currently loaded topology settings? I tried describe cluster but didn't see that information. thanks.

Comment: If you start the cassandra-cli then `use myks;` then `describe;` it should give you your replication strategy and options right near the top of the output;